# I am not seeing any updates related to the Windows 10 technical preview

Tags: windows-10-preview

I'm currently on version 9926, but no matter which "ring" I pick (fast or slow), I do not see any updates available for Windows 10 itself. I do see updates related to things like Office and Visual Studio though.

Comment: Download the current build's .iso file and upgrade manually.

Comment: It is an option

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear there. I've already got it downloaded and everything, I just wasn't sure if there was something I was missing before I went that route.

Comment: I thought that said "it wasn't" an option.

Comment: go to http://insider.windows.com -- you can get version 10074

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't provide a solution for updating your current Build of Windows TP to the latest build. You can only update your build to the latest only by downloading it from [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/preview-iso) and performing a fresh installation. These are just the preview of what is the come in the final build of the Windows 10. Once the final build is available you will be able to update via Windows Store (As happened for Windows 8) or by downloading the iso.